# Returning edge properties in gremlin using tree function

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

Query

```
g.withSack(0).V().hasLabel('A').has('label_A','A').union(__.emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(1)).in()),emit().repeat(sack(sum).by(constant(-1)).out())).project('level','properties').by(sack()).by(tree().by(valueMap().by(unfold())).unfold().unfold())
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "level": 0,
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "label_A": "A"
            },
            "value": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "level": 1,
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "label_A": "A"
            },
            "value": {
                "{label_B="B"}": {}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "level": 2,
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "label_A": "A"
            },
            "value": {
                "{label_B=B}": {
                    "{label_C=C}": {}
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

The query only returns the properties of nodes. Please modify the query so that it returns properties of nodes as well as relations respectively in tree format.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the properties of the edges you need to pass through them, split the `out` and `in` steps into `outE().inV()` and `inE().outV()`. then the tree step will take them into account.

Also if you want to specify the return value on the edges you can add a second `by` modulator to the tree step.

```
g.withSack(0).V().hasLabel('material').
  has('label_A', 'A').union(
    __.emit().repeat(sack(sum).
        by(constant(1)).
      inE().outV()),
    emit().repeat(sack(sum).
        by(constant(-1)).
      outE().inV())
  ).
  project('level', 'properties').by(sack()).
    by(tree().
        by(valueMap().by(unfold())).
        by(valueMap()))
```

example: https://gremlify.com/rixszg1ougl